# How to get file stream from the sharepoint file url in dynamic crm plugin?

Tags: sharepoint, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, sharepoint-online

I have requirement to get file stream of share point file, for the that I have share point file URL.

https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/documents/contact/test/Beat01_07262017.pdf

I’m trying to connect to SharePoint Online (using CSOM) from within a plugin in CRM Online . For that to work, I merged the SharePoint Client and Client.Runtime DLL’s with ilmerge.exe into my plugin DLL. But as soon as the following code:

```csh
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(server);
clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(UserId, Password); // This line throws an below exception:
```

> Request for the permission of type
>   ‘System.Security.Permissions.RegistryPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089′
>   failed.

Is there any way to make it working?

I have checked with [SharePoint Integration from CRM Online Workflow/Plugin](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-Integration-c5f21604/sourcecode?fileId=131706&pathId=1370335438) but not able to get it working 
and getting error as below

> **Exception:** Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> **Stack Trace** at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[]
>   arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
>               at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj,
>   Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
>               at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
>               at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.DynamicInvoke(Delegate project,
>   Object[] args)
>               at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateExpressionToConditionValue(Expression
>   exp, ParameterExpression[] parameters)
>               at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateWhereCondition(BinaryExpression
>   be, FilterExpressionWrapper parentFilter, Func 2 getFilter, Func 2
>   getLinkLookup, Boolean negate)
>               at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateWhere(String
>   parameterName, BinaryExpression be, FilterExpressionWrapper
>   parentFilter, Func 2 getFilter, List 1 linkLookups, Boolean
>   negate)
>               at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateWhereBoolean(String
>   parameterName, Expression exp, FilterExpressionWrapper parentFilter,
>   Func 2 getFilter, List 1 linkLookups, BinaryExpression parent, Boolean
>   negate)
>               at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.TranslateWhere(QueryExpression
>   qe, String parameterName, Expression exp, List 1 linkLookups)
>               at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.GetQueryExpression(Expression
>   expression, Boolean& throwIfSequenceIsEmpty, Boolean&
>   throwIfSequenceNotSingle, Projection& projection,
>   NavigationSource& source, List 1& linkLookups)
>               at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.Execute[TElement](Expression
>   expression)
>               at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Linq.QueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression
>   expression)
>               at System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IQueryable 1
>   source)
>               at CRMPluginProject1._365Immo.Laurus.SharePoint.DocumentLocationHelper.GetDocumentLocationPath(SharePointDocumentLocation
>   parentLocation)
>               at CRMPluginProject1._365Immo.Laurus.SharePoint.DocumentLocationHelper.CreateDocumentLocation(Entity
>   site, String documentLibraryName, EntityReference
>   regardingRecord)
>               at CRMPluginProject1._365Immo.Laurus.Plugins.GetSharePointFile.Execute(IServiceProvider
>   serviceProvider)
>
> Inner Exception :
>   The demand failed due to the code access security information captured during the creation of an anonymously hosted
>   dynamic method. In order for this operation to succeed, ensure that
>   the demand would have succeeded at the time the method was created.
>   See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=288746 for more
>   information.
>
> Stack Trace :    at lambda_method(Closure )

Answer (score 1):

The SharePoint client library apparently needs access to the Windows registry. This is not allowed in sandboxed CRM plugins.

In sandboxed plugins code is only allowed to access resources on the web using the http or https protocol. (IP addresses are not allowed either.)

Comment: I have requirement to access file from share point. how can i achieve it? For Upload file from CRM to Sharepoint i have used thirdparty Addon and it return the file URL. like "https://mysite.sharepoint.com/sites/documents/contact/test/Beat01_07262017.pdf"